# Android -- How to post app rating/comments to Market from within app?

Tags: android, comments, rating, google-play, marketplace

This is a simple question. Is there a way to allow users to enter in a comment and or rating for my app from directly within my app and have that data posted back to the Android Market? If so, what would the code for that look like if I used an EditText view to allow user input? If not, then is my only other option directly linking to my app in the Market (i.e. the user clicks the link in my app, or a button, and the Market app launches with my app page displayed)? For example:

```
view.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity( new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
           Uri.parse("market://details?id=packagename") ) );
    }
}
```

*where "packagename" is replaced by my app's package name from the manifest.

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK there are no Market APIs exposed yet...great suggestion to add, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there will not be market access for a while. That would need further special application permissions (donwload, buy, rate) as your app then could download and rate any app in the market.

As there are many security complaints an Android based on the fact that users doesn't read the Permissions they accept, I think Google would not expose the market that fast but channel the users through one well known market app.

Comment: Honestly, I could accept to go through the Android market app. It's just a pity the URL cannot be more precise, like `market://details?id=packagename#rate`

Answer (score 7):

No. You can only direct it to the android market URL. There is no provision to get the rating or comment as input from the user.

If its so, I will post 5 stars rating, even if user has given only 2 stars : )

Comment: Or even better, rate on startup, without asking them their advice. Those users always underate our apps anyway.