# Android app: where to send user for Market app rating?

Tags: android, rating

from within my Android app i'm installing a system to ask user to go rate app on google play.
Only documentation I found, is to send user to `market://details?id=packagename`.
Isn't there a way to send user directly to the rating page so he can directly enter stars and comment, like is possible from iOS app ?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875630/android-how-to-post-app-rating-comments-to-market-from-within-app

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, there are no anchors on the market for the "rating" section, so you couldn't even try something like #rating. There is no API that I know of that can send in a rating from the application itself.

I think your only option is to do what you're currently doing. The only disadvantage is the user has to scroll down a little bit. (I'm not entirely sure how the Google Play app works since I'm still stuck with the Market [Blame ATT] )