# Rate this app in android

Tags: android

I am trying to create the usual rate my app feature in my app. I know we can send an activity to the playstore using the following line:

```
   String appPackageName= getPackageName();
   Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id="+appPackageName));
marketIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
startActivity(marketIntent);
```

But instead of directing to playstore is it possible to directly open the feedback page like the below in playstore?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library `AppRate` from [here](https://github.com/delight-im/AppRater) on `GitHub` or the direct way like you showed above in your post to open the app's market page. But it is not possible to open the prompt screen. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875630/android-how-to-post-app-rating-comments-to-market-from-within-app?rq=1) post assumes, that it isn't allowed, to controll some market function via API to prevent abuses.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this library does not directly open the feedback page as the question asked.

Comment: Quote from  the GitHub page "The prompting dialog will be displayed (if adequate) as soon as you call show() on your AppRater instance"

Comment: Which is just an AlertDialog within your own app?

Comment: Yes and then opens an Intent with new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(String.format(mTargetUri, mPackageName))). The code is available on GitHub so you can have a look at it...

Comment: I did. The target uri is just `market://details?id=packagename`. This does not automatically open the rate dialog in the Play Store app.

Comment: @Alex I tried this just now. I am not getting the feedback window directly. It is still sending me to playstore.

Comment: Ok, i see. Then according to that post it isn't possible:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875630/android-how-to-post-app-rating-comments-to-market-from-within-app?rq=1 I correct my answer to make it useful for googlers.